# How to switch directly to a pane in Tmux?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to switch directly to a pane in Tmux, by pane #.

How can I do this? I know how to cycle between panes, and move to panes that are beside the current pane.

I'd like to be able to run the `display-panes` command, which shows the "pane #" on each pane, then later on jump directly to a pane using the pane #'s that were displayed by `display-panes`.

Is this possible?

NOTE: And just to be clear, I don't mean window, I mean pane. Thanks!

Comment: is there any way to focus the currently highlighted pane using the direction keys to navigate panes? eg I up arrow to be sent to bash and not tmux after the current pane is selected... the timeout drives me crazy

Comment: none that I know of

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can jump directly to a pane by typing pane's index while it is showed by `display-panes` command.

From `man tmux`:

```
display-panes [-t target-client]
                   (alias: displayp)
             Display a visible indicator of each pane shown by target-client.
             See the display-panes-time, display-panes-colour, and
             display-panes-active-colour session options.  While the indicator
             is on screen, a pane may be selected with the ‘0’ to ‘9’ keys.
```

Or instead of typing command, you can use:

```
C-b q
```

- `C-b` send prefix key
- `q` display panes indexes

Comment: If the pane #'s show too quick for you to select a pane, use the following in your `.tmux.conf` file to change the amount of time the pane #'s are displayed. `set display-panes-time 4000` Note that you can hit the `esc` key to cancel the operation if you want

Comment: Can you also so up and down, right and left instead of using a number?

Comment: The `set display-panes-time 4000` works nicely, however, there is one edge case I hit that is just a minor thing but would be good to know how to get around it. If I have my default shell set to tmux and use guake to launch into it, the first time I get an `/home/elynn/.tmux.conf:92: no current session` warning.

Comment: K, looks like `-g` works, `set -g display-panes-time 4000`

Comment: Furthermore if you open more than 10 tmux panes, it is not easy or impossible to move a specific pane using `C-b <pane #>` when the pane index is larger than 10. In that case, `C-b <arrow keys>` would be useful to navigate panes and move the focus around panes.

Answer (score 32):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> (the tmux default prefix sequence plus `q`) will briefly display the pane indexes, if you enter the index number while they are displayed, your cursor will move to that pane.

If you have a large number of panes and the display time is too short, you can configure tmux to display the index for a specified interval with the `display-panes-time` option in your `~/.tmux.conf`. The value is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 12):

When you know the **indicator** of your target-pane (e.g. by `display-panes`), you can directly switch to this pane with `select-pane`.

From `man tmux`:

```
select-pane [-DdegLlMmRU] [-P style] [-T title] [-t target-pane]
                   (alias: selectp)
             Make pane target-pane the active pane in window target-window,
             or set its style (with -P).
```

Say you want to switch to the pane with the indicator **2**, type:

```
C-b : select-pane -t 2
```

or the alias

```
C-b : selectp -t 2
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this isn't necessarily what you asked for, but [enabling mouse support](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/enable-mouse-support-in-tmux-on-os-x/) is pretty easy and most terminal emulators support it.

You may simply click on the pane you want to switch to. :)